# Как решить проблему с axios, почему axois направляет запросы на https?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

В настоящее время я разрабатываю мини-сайт, и там вам нужно выполнить поиск по городу. Во время поиска нужно отобразить варианты. Например: пользователь написал "Моs", и появляется всплывающее окно, в котором отображаются города, такие как Моs, Моsta, Moscow и т.д.

и я получаю все эти данные через http://api.positionstack.com/v1/ , там у меня есть базовая бесплатная подписка, где нет https encryption, мне это вообще не нужно
До этого API работал без проблем, я получал города через префиксы и названия, с помощью axios я написал этот код (скриншоты)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но однажды что-то сломалось, и я заметил, что, несмотря на то, что я написал протокол http, axios перенаправляет запрос на протокол https, а этот API говорит, что запрещает доступ, так как у меня бесплатная подписка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я получаю ответы в Postman с http

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В документации говорится, что вы можете ссылаться на http для бесплатного использования и https для платного использования

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить проблему с axios, почему axois направляет запросы на https

Comment: попробуйте удалить заголовок из html, если таковой имеется
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">

Comment: Я разрабатываю проект на React, и я не знаю, где его найти, чтобы удалить его, как отключить Content-Security-Policy на react